# How to make wxPython StaticText selectable

Tags: wxpython

The other day I found out, much to my surprise, that static text on a wxPython panel is not selectable/highlightable. I'd need that so the user could copy the content.

I didn't find a flag or the like to make the `StaticText` component selectable.

```
import wx
app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello, World!")
panel = wx.Panel(frame)
panel.SetBackgroundColour("#FFB6C1")
st = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello, World!")
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few experiments I settled for creating my custom HTML-enabled tooltip window. Here's the current version from the [gist](https://gist.github.com/marcelstoer/85701bf76c00837195761f70f93d8801) (wish SO allowed to embed rather than copy this):

```
import wx
import wx.html
import webbrowser


class HtmlPopupTransientWindow(wx.PopupTransientWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, style, html_body_content, bgcolor, size):
        wx.PopupTransientWindow.__init__(self, parent, style)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour(bgcolor)

        html_window = self.HtmlWindow(panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=size)
        html_window.SetPage('<body bgcolor="' + bgcolor + '">' + html_body_content + '</body>')

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(html_window, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        sizer.Fit(panel)
        sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

    class HtmlWindow(wx.html.HtmlWindow):
        def OnLinkClicked(self, link):
            # get a hold of the PopupTransientWindow to close it
            self.GetParent().GetParent().Dismiss()
            webbrowser.open(link.GetHref())
```

See https://frightanic.com/software-development/create-an-info-icon-with-wxpython/ for further explanations.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a way to make `StaticText` selectable/copyable but here are 2 hacks to get around the problem.
1. Copy to clipboard on right mouse click
2. `TextCtrl` masquerading as a `StaticText`

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.st = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello, World! Copy me with right click",pos=(5,5))
        self.st.Bind(wx.wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN,self.ShowPopup)
        self.tc = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Paste here", pos=(5,30),size=(300,20))
        self.tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY,"TextCtrl masquerading as StaticText - Select me",style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.NO_BORDER,pos=(5,60),size=(300,20))
        self.tc2.SetBackgroundColour(self.panel.GetBackgroundColour())
        self.Show()

    def ShowPopup(self,event):
        popmenu = wx.Menu()
        popmenu.Append(1, "Copy this text to clipboard")
        popmenu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.Copy)
        self.panel.PopupMenu(popmenu)
        popmenu.Destroy()

    def Copy(self,event):
        clipdata = wx.TextDataObject()
        text = self.st.GetLabelText()
        clipdata.SetText(text)
        wx.TheClipboard.Open()
        wx.TheClipboard.SetData(clipdata)
        wx.TheClipboard.Close()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you Rolf. I found out that using `HtmlWindow` instead of `StaticText` can be a workaround in some cases.

Comment: I am intrigued. I don't seem to be able to get `HtmlWindow` to allow selection on Linux. Perhaps you should self answer.

Comment: I'll consider that if a) no one comes forward with an alternative and b) I've gained a little more experience with that. I've yet to figure out where that component _can_ be used and where not.

Comment: The "answer" is now documented.